# Banned because of a Windows 7 related question?

Tags: discussion

Yes, I've been banned again. Though this time I can't seem to understand the true reason why.

It's because I got a downvote on a [Windows 7 related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1653483/audiodg-issues-in-windows-7). I know that Windows 7 has reached its EOL and the downvote that triggered the ban algorithm was surely from that, but some users still prefer it (**with virus protection enabled**, mind you).

As for the question itself, no one said it was unclear or anything, just to "upgrade to Windows 10". Sure enough, my brother is going to upgrade and ditch Windows 7 (since the audio issues have been really irritating), but shouldn't I have gotten at least a speculation on what is wrong with the audiodg.exe process?

I fully acknowledge that Windows 7 has some security holes and other disadvantages compared to Windows 10, such as support for newer hardware, but isn't Super User here to [**answer questions** targeting **any audience**](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3159/774036)? As a tech-savvy user, I don't think that I got an elaborate in-depth answer.

> *they just told him to "upgrade to Windows 10" without any speculation
> on what the issue could be.* No-one cares what the issue might be. -- *@Tetsujin (part 1)*

This does not seem like an elaborate answer/comment to me.

> He needs to get off Win7, else the 'reason his machine slows down' is
> because of all the botnets it's part of. -- *@Tetsujin (part 2)*

As I mentioned above, AV protection **is enabled** and he is careful when he downloads stuff from the web. I just did not include it as it was totally unrelated to the issue. Also, I never mentioned any slowdowns, just random audio cutoffs and freezes that are irritating, but can be mostly mitigated.

*Also, there seem to be more Windows 7 related questions than Windows 10 ones on Super User (46.9k > 33.8k), and the tag does not state that the OS is EOL, unlike with older Ubuntu versions in Ask Ubuntu. From this, it seems that Windows 7 questions are accepted, if not upvoted.*

[image: windows-7 tag]
[image: windows-10 tag]

> the old Windows 7 doesn't and couldn't possibly support such hardware
> reliably. End of story. -- *@ChanganAuto*

The motherboard **does** in fact [support Windows 7](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x/sp#sp), just to a lesser extent. Plus, if the hardware is "Windows 10 only", then why would Gigabyte include the Realtek audio drivers for Windows 7 in their driver disc supplied in the board's box? (Gigabyte A320M-S2H)

[image: OS support from Gigabyte's official page for the board]

[image: Win7 folder in the Realtek audio driver installer folder]

> Since the board was designed specifically for Windows 10, upgrading to
> Windows 10 is now the most sensible solution. -- *@John*

"Sensible" seems more useful and nice than "nobody cares" and "end of story" to both audiences, in my opinion.

***Note:** I'm not attacking Tetsujin or ChanganAuto personally here, just stating that their answers weren't helpful at all for me and probably got me banned. Anyone else could have been in their position, I don't know who downvoted.*

*If you two happen to read this, please don't take it personally.*

### Conclusion

I'm not trying to justify my brother's choice of keeping his Windows 7 installation over a fresh, better and clean Windows 10 installation, but [operating systems are a **personal preference**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dtCc1E3t5M), as long as they are supported (at least by the software my brother uses, which still does). Just like with Fedora or Arch over Ubuntu/Mint, FL Studio over Ableton Live, PC over Mac, etc.,  you get the point. It may not be the best solution, but it's **his PC**, not mine or anyone else's.

***Addition:** If it was another system with Windows 7 installed just for experimentation purposes, I'm sure that my question would have been upvoted (or left with 0 votes) and I would get some more helpful answers/comments. Did I get downvoted only because it's Windows 7 on a daily driver system? You can't just force someone to upgrade if they don't want to. (Remember GWX?)*

Comment: The motherboard only supports Windows 7 with certain AMD processors, which doesn't include the one your brother has. The answer to your issue, to upgrade to Windows 10, is the one you say is off the table. So this is not a useful question you have posted. The tooltip suggests downvoting questions that are not useful. Not that anyone has to justify what they consider useful in a question.

Comment: The "true reason" is the same as your previous question. You have *a lot* of old deleted questions and your account is on the cusp of a ban. The main reason is probably right in the [ban help](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) at the bottom `If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. Your ban is immediately reinstated once that question is posted, but a single question could be enough to lift you out of the block.`

Comment: Related https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14470/ban-reinstated-when-i-asked-a-new-question-after-the-existing-one-but-is-not-li

Comment: @n8te I know that it's not supported, but the weird thing is that it was functioning perfectly for about 2 months before the audio driver decided to screw things up. That's why I want to know what is *really* happening. As I said above, he is going to upgrade to Windows 10, but he is also really curious as to why this happens when no hardware was changed (he cannot recall any major software changes, the drivers were left intact from the moment of the OS installation).

Answer (score 3):

> Yes, I've been banned again. Though this time I can't seem to understand the true reason why.

You were question banned due to your history of asking low quality questions that are not well received by the community.  Your most recent question does not really contain any information that can diagnose the behavior you describe about the audio cutting out.

> It's because I got a downvote on a Windows 7 related question. I know that Windows 7 has reached its EOL and the downvote that triggered the ban algorithm was surely from that, but some users still prefer it (with virus protection enabled, mind you).

You don’t actually know the reason for the downvote, but your question provided absolutely no information, about the hardware which means it’s difficult to diagnose the issue.  If a question cannot be diagnosed then it cannot be answered.

> As for the question itself, no one said it was unclear or anything, just to "upgrade to Windows 10". Sure enough, my brother is going to upgrade and ditch Windows 7 (since the audio issues have been really irritating), but shouldn't I have gotten at least a speculation on what is wrong with the audiodg.exe process?

You should flag any comment that suggests the solution to a problem like this is to upgrade to Windows 10 and downvote any answers that suggest that is the solution.

> The motherboard does in fact support Windows 7, just to a lesser extent. Plus, if the hardware is "Windows 10 only", then why would Gigabyte include the Realtek audio drivers for Windows 7 in their driver disc supplied in the board's box? (Gigabyte A320M-S2H)

They wouldn’t which means the audio issues likely have nothing to do with the fact the device is running Windows 7.

> Did I get downvoted only because it's Windows 7 on a daily driver system? You can't just force someone to upgrade if they don't want to. (Remember GWX?)

Your question was downvoted due to its low quality.